# Click function to scroll div not working

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the jfiddle of code I have that is suppose to move the div (50px right now) when the right arrow button is clicked. However, I seem to be missing something as it will not scroll when I push the button.  Using chrome inspect I see that the javascript is being executed with 'view' being 15px

https://jsfiddle.net/cm014krh/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="sortable-outer">
  <div class="pc-row sortable">
    <div class="pc-col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="pc-col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="pc-col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="pc-col-xs-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bnr-fpc-fs-controls-control right lg left-arrow-button">
  <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="carousel_arrow" x="287" y="384.561">
    <path d="M16 0c8.836 0 16 7.164 16 16s-7.164 16-16 16S0 24.836 0 16 7.164 0 16 0zm0 29c7.168 0 13-5.832 13-13S23.168 3 16 3 3 8.832 3 16s5.832 13 13 13zM13.5 9c.39 0 .743.153 1.01.398l.004-.003 6 5.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 2.21l-6 5.5-.003-.003c-.267.245-.62.398-1.01.398a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5-1.5c0-.438.19-.828.49-1.102l-.004-.003L17.28 16l-4.794-4.395.003-.003A1.49 1.49 0 0 1 12 10.5 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13.5 9z"
    fill="#818091" fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="bnr-fpc-fs-controls-control next lg right-arrow-button">
  <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="carousel_arrow" x="287" y="384.561">
    <path d="M16 0c8.836 0 16 7.164 16 16s-7.164 16-16 16S0 24.836 0 16 7.164 0 16 0zm0 29c7.168 0 13-5.832 13-13S23.168 3 16 3 3 8.832 3 16s5.832 13 13 13zM13.5 9c.39 0 .743.153 1.01.398l.004-.003 6 5.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 2.21l-6 5.5-.003-.003c-.267.245-.62.398-1.01.398a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5-1.5c0-.438.19-.828.49-1.102l-.004-.003L17.28 16l-4.794-4.395.003-.003A1.49 1.49 0 0 1 12 10.5 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13.5 9z"
    fill="#818091" fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sortable {
  min-width: 729px;
}

.sortable-outer {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.pc-row {
  width: 1750px;
}

.pc-col-xs-4 {
  width: 320px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.left-arrow-button {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.left-arrow-button:hover, .right-arrow-button:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and the javascript:

```
$('.right-arrow-button').click(function() {
  var view = $('.sortable');
  var move = "50px";
  var sliderLimit = -234;

  var currentPosition = parseInt($('.sortable').offset().left);
  if (currentPosition >= sliderLimit) $('.sortable').stop(false, true).animate({
    left: "-=" + move
  }, {
    duration: 400
  });
});
```

Comment: Is [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/cm014krh/4/) what you're trying to achieve? You're trying to animate the inside content, when you should be animating the div with the scrollbar, `sortable-outer`. In such a case, you'd use `scrollLeft`, not `left`.

Comment: @Santi that is exactly what I'm trying to do. The source I used only used left, but it looks like they did it that way because they had their div the full length and just adjusted it as needed using 'left'. Thank you.  If you make a full comment I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what's going wrong is here is two-fold:

**1.** You're trying to animate the *inner* div, though I believe you should be scrolling the *outer* div, which is `sortable-outer`.

**2.** In such a case where you're trying to scroll, you probably want to use `scrollLeft`, not just `left`.

```js
var $view = $('.sortable');
var move = "50px";

$('.right-arrow-button').click(function() {
    var currentPosition = parseInt($view.offset().left);
    $('.sortable-outer').stop(false, true).animate({
        scrollLeft: "+=" + move
    }, {
        duration: 400
    });
});


$('.left-arrow-button').click(function() {
    var currentPosition = parseInt($view.offset().left);
    $('.sortable-outer').stop(false, true).animate({
        scrollLeft: "-=" + move
    }, {
        duration: 400
    });
});
```

```css
.sortable {
    min-width: 729px;
}

.sortable-outer {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.pc-row {
    width: 1750px;
}

.pc-col-xs-4 {
    width: 320px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.left-arrow-button {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.left-arrow-button:hover,
.right-arrow-button:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sortable-outer">
    <div class="pc-row sortable">
        <div class="pc-col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="pc-col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="pc-col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="pc-col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bnr-fpc-fs-controls-control right lg left-arrow-button">
    <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="carousel_arrow" x="287" y="384.561">
        <path d="M16 0c8.836 0 16 7.164 16 16s-7.164 16-16 16S0 24.836 0 16 7.164 0 16 0zm0 29c7.168 0 13-5.832 13-13S23.168 3 16 3 3 8.832 3 16s5.832 13 13 13zM13.5 9c.39 0 .743.153 1.01.398l.004-.003 6 5.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 2.21l-6 5.5-.003-.003c-.267.245-.62.398-1.01.398a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5-1.5c0-.438.19-.828.49-1.102l-.004-.003L17.28 16l-4.794-4.395.003-.003A1.49 1.49 0 0 1 12 10.5 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13.5 9z"
        fill="#818091" fill-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="bnr-fpc-fs-controls-control next lg right-arrow-button">
    <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="carousel_arrow" x="287" y="384.561">
        <path d="M16 0c8.836 0 16 7.164 16 16s-7.164 16-16 16S0 24.836 0 16 7.164 0 16 0zm0 29c7.168 0 13-5.832 13-13S23.168 3 16 3 3 8.832 3 16s5.832 13 13 13zM13.5 9c.39 0 .743.153 1.01.398l.004-.003 6 5.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 2.21l-6 5.5-.003-.003c-.267.245-.62.398-1.01.398a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5-1.5c0-.438.19-.828.49-1.102l-.004-.003L17.28 16l-4.794-4.395.003-.003A1.49 1.49 0 0 1 12 10.5 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13.5 9z"
        fill="#818091" fill-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- `$('.sortable')` captures nothing.
- You want `scrollLeft`, not `left`. `left` refers to the object's position's offset, i.e. it will move the item right by the `left` value.
- You don't need suffix `px` for the move value.
- You don't need guard the animation because it will never scroll past the limits.

Here's the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/cm014krh/5/